# How to know a textbox is Bold and Italic or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

When a text is ***bold and italic***. I was try to find out It is italic or not? But I failed.

```
if (txtText.Text.Font.Style == FontStyle.Italic)
        txtText.Font = new Font(txtText.Font, txtText.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Italic);
```

.
.

By this way,

```
 if (txtText.Text.Font.Style == FontStyle.Bold)
        txtText.Font = new Font(txtText.Font, txtText.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Italic);
```

I only know the text is **Bold** or not.

Comment: Does `(txtText.Text.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold) == FontStyle.Bold` work? I haven't tried it.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check equality like that to check if a particular bit is set.

To check if the `FontStyle.Italic` bit is set, do:

```
//True if italic is set
if ((textText.Text.Font.Style & FontStyle.Italic) != 0)
```

This works because every bit *besides* the one for `FontStyle.Italic` will be 0 in the result, and that bit will be 0 if it was 0 in the current style. Thus, if the current style has it set, the result will be non-zero, and zero if it isn't set.

Also note that because you are using XOR below it, you will *always* just toggle the current setting of italic rather than set/unset it explicitly. Thus, your check may not even be necessary.

Comment: I don't know when this changed, but in Visual Studio 2019 the test would be "if(textText.Font.Bold  || textText.Font.Italic)"